# Remove "sharing" from Excel workbook

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to save a workbook to a new location with a password and keep the filename the same. The filname gets updated weekly with a date appended to it, so it's never the same. There are two things I'm having trouble with:

1. Using the SaveAs method to save the file with the same name in a different path &
2. I can't add a password because the workbook is shared.

I'm scripting this out in PowerShell, and if possible, I'd like to unshare the workbook in the script. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a method that accomplishes this. Here is what I have so far... I really appreciate any advice.

```
$xls = new-object -com excel.application 
$xls.Visible = $False
$xlsWB = $xls.Workbooks.Open("path\*.xlsx")
$xlsWB.Password = "Password"                                        
$xlsWB.SaveAs("differentPath\*.xlsx")
$xls.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xls)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xlsWB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, there is a method that can be called to change the sharing status of the workbook. It's ExclusiveAccess().

Here is my working code that solved the problem:

```
$xls = new-object -comObject excel.application 
$xls.Visible = $False
$xls.DisplayAlerts = $False
$xlsWB = $xls.Workbooks.Open("FilePath")
$xlsWB.ExclusiveAccess()
$xlsWB.Password = "AddThisPassword"                                     
$xlsWB.Save()
$xlsWB.Close()
$xls.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xls)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xlsWB)

move "CurrentPath" "NewPath"
```

Once I change the sharing status of the workbook, the Password method successfully adds a password to the workbook, solving the second issue described in the OP. Rather than use SaveAs(), I decided to simply move the file, which saves me from deleting the source file.

Thanks and I hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

this was my attempt at a similar problem.  It removes the MultiUserEditing of files within a folder structure.

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem "C:\path_to_reports\" -File -Filter "*.xls" -recurse))
{
    #The filter seems to also work for *.xlxsx        
    $Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible = $False
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False

    $ExcelWorkbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($file.fullname)
    If ($ExcelWorkbook.MultiUserEditing -eq "True")
    {
        $ExcelWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess()                                 
        $ExcelWorkbook.Save()
    }
    #close the workbook and not the file
    $ExcelWorkbook.Close()
    #Quit the file
    $Excel.Quit()

    #cleanup
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    #more clean up
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelWorkbook) 

    #the most clean up
    Remove-Variable -Name excel
}
```